# Аутентификация с помощью Spring Security + Angular

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security

Не совсем понятно как обработать(реализовать правильно сервис) данные username и password. Данные username и password  находятся в базе. Подскажите идеи в каком направлении двигать.

login.html

```
<div class="container">
    <p><br/></p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: transparent">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1>Log in</h1>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Start Form-->
                    <form method="post" name="loginForm">
                        <!-- Start gorm-group username-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username or email</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="icon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userLogin" id="exampleInputEmail1" ng-model="username">
                            </div>
                            <label id="userLoginLabel" for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Start gorm-group password-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>

                            <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="icon2"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="userPassword" id="exampleInputPassword1" ng-model="password">
                            </div>
                            <label id="passwordLabel" for="exampleInputPassword1" style="color:red"></label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe">Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <hr/>
                        <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="loginSubmit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="login()">Log in</button>
                        <a href="#">
                            <button type="button" name="signUpSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Register
                            </button>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </form>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    </script>
                    <!-- End Form-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

LoginController.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Login').controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $state, $cookies, AuthenticationService) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        AuthenticationService.signIn($scope.username, $scope.password,
            function onSuccess(payload) {
                $state.go("dashboard");
            },
            function onError() {
                $state.go("login");
            }
        );
    }
});
```

AuthenticationService.js

```
'use strict';

app.factory('AuthenticationService', function (Network, $cookies) {
    return {

        signIn: function (username, password, onSuccess, onError) {
            Network.sendPost("/services/authentication/signIn",
                    {"login": username, "password": password},
                    onSuccess, onError);
        },

        signOut: function(onSuccess) {
            Network.sendGet("/services/authentication/signOut", {}, onSuccess);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Вам надо на стороне сервера или на стороне UI обрабатывать? И что вы хотите с ними(данными) сделать.

Comment: Мне необходимо обработать на стороне сервера и каким-то образом сообщить статус (ОК или ошибка). Данные нужны для того,чтобы Spring Security создал полноценный объект Authentication и положил его в SecurityContextHolder.

Answer (score 1):

Я делал так, при открытии страницы шлю запрос на сервер, сервер проверяет сессию, находит пользователя возвращает данные, если данные норм то пользователь авторизован, это всё находится в директиве меню и сервисе авторизации, то есть если обновится на какой то странице  будет отправлен запрос и получен ответ

```
 $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {
                    url = $location.url();
```

Эта штука проверяет права пользователя и скидывает его раньше загрузки страницы

Comment: А каким образом сервер находит пользователя? Используется ли для этого authentication-manager в сервисе?

Comment: по сессии находит пользователя, authentication-manager  не использую